# Simple travelling ratio problem? Do we need to first find the distance?

Tags: ratio, kinematics

A car and a truck start off from Town A and Town B respectively and travel towards each other. The ratio of the speed of the car and the truck is 2 : 3. If it takes 5.5 hours for the car to travel from Town A to Town B, how long will it take for them to meet?

Somehow I only managed to find the time taken for the truck to reach Town A from Town B, which is 11/3 hours; but I still could not find the time taken for them to meet? I noticed that if we can find the distance of AB then we can solve the problem, but how can we find the distance? Is there anyway besides finding the distance between Town A and Town B?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the speed of car is $x$ and the speed of the truck is $y$ , then their relative speed is $x+y$. $\therefore$ the ratio of speed of car to relative speed is 2:5.

Now the car takes 5.5 hours to cover the distance, thus the time taken to cover the same distance with their relative speed would be $\frac{5.5*2}{5} = \frac{11}{5} = $ 2.2 hours.

(The time taken for them to meet is the time required to cover the complete distance with their relative speed.)